# Cambiar el color de una Row en una GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Buenas,

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Framework 3.5 en WPF (xaml) y el problema que se me presenta es que a la hora de querer cambiar el color de una linea des del código de la clase, cuando la grid ya tiene los datos que quiero mostrar, no encuentro la manera.

Código XAML:

```
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=position}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="position"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.NombreArchivo}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=filename}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="filename" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.FechaInicio}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=startdate}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="startdate" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.FechaFin}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=enddate}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="enddate"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.UltimaCopia}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=lastbackup}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="lastbackup"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.Estado}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=state}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="state"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.Periodicidad}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=period}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="period"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.Ruta}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=path}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="path"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Properties.Resources.EspacioActual}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=actualsize}" my:clsGridViewSort.PropertyName="actualsize"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es cambiar el color de una fila o de una columna?

Comment: De una fila, lo he puesto como linea en la explicación, ahora lo cambio para que sea mas claro.

Comment: Lo mejor en estos casos es usar triggers. [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126582/579895) tienes un ejemplo

Comment: El tema está en que no son filas con un valor especifico las que necesito cambiar de color, sino que dependiendo de unos cálculos unas se pondrán en un color y otras no.

Comment: es igual @MarcPuig. Lo mejor es que expongas una propiedad donde almacenes el resultado de los calculos y uses esa propiedad como trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este ejemplo las filas del gridview cambian de color según el valor de estado (3: rojo, 2: amarillo)

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfCambiarColorRowGridview.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Estado}" Value="3">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Estado}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="NombreArchivo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NombreArchivo}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FechaInicio" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FechaInicio}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Estado" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Estado}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfCambiarColorRowGridview
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Archivo> items = new List<Archivo>();
            items.Add(new Archivo() { NombreArchivo = "file01.txt", FechaInicio = new DateTime(2017,7,1), Estado = 1 });
            items.Add(new Archivo() { NombreArchivo = "file02.txt", FechaInicio = new DateTime(2017, 7, 2), Estado = 2 });
            items.Add(new Archivo() { NombreArchivo = "file03.txt", FechaInicio = new DateTime(2017, 7, 3), Estado = 3 });
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }

    public class Archivo
    {
        public string NombreArchivo { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }

        public int Estado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este ejemplo si se acerca mas a lo que pide OP. Buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

tambien puedes hacer algo como:

```
<Border Name="ClearButtonBorder" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="0,3,3,0">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="X" />
    </Border>
```

esto seria un trigger para mauseover.

Comment: En este caso sería un DataTrigger lo necesario, con lo que aunque no va desencaminado en realidad esto no responde los requerimientos del OP