# Colorear filas según condición WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xaml, mvvm

estoy trabajando con WPF y MVVM y estoy teniendo un problema al querer usar un `enum`  para determinar el color de las filas de un `DataGrid`.

Tengo un ViewModel que se ve más o menos así

```
public class DespieceViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ArticuloItemViewModel> mItemList;    
    public ICollectionView<ArticuloItemViewModel> Items { get; }

    public DespieceViewModel()
    {
        //Acá iría la lógica con la que lleno mItemList
        Items = new MyCollectionViewGeneric<ArticuloItemViewModel>(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mItemList));            
    }
}
```

Aclaro que la implementación de `ICollectionView<T>` existe sólo para tener IntelliSense en XAML, no tiene ningún cambio con la original, de todos modos dejo el enlace a la [clase en github](https://gist.github.com/juanch0x/1876d36223b703d4da2acf797bc53c87) por las dudas

El ViewModel `ArticuloItemViewModel` es sencillo, sería algo así

```
public class ArticuloItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
{    
    public string CodigoPadre { get; set; }
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    public EstadoArticuloDespiece Estado { get; set; }        
}
```

El enum `EstadoArticuloDespiece` sería el siguiente:

```
public enum EstadoArticuloDespiece
{
    Ok,
    Inexistente,
    Duplicado
}
```

Para este enum tengo un pequeño `Converter` que simplemente usa un `switch` y devuelve un `SolidColorBrush` según cual es el valor.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, estoy intentando Bindear el color de fila de un `DataGrid` basados en `EstadoArticuloDespiece`

Lo hago de la siguiente manera (basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14735875/5213794)):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Estado, Converter={StaticResource EstadoToBrushValueConverter}}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Código Padre" Binding="{Binding Path=CodigoPadre}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Código Delfos" Binding="{Binding Path=CodigoDelfos}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Las columnas con su información se muestran sin problemas, pero el color no cambia y ReSharper me marca error en `Color="{Binding Path=Estado}"` diciéndome:

> Cannot resolve property `Estado` in data context of type..

¿En qué estoy fallando? ¿Cómo debe bindearse esta propiedad?

*Aclaro que `BaseViewModel` implementa `PropertyChanged` para todas las propiedades.*

Comment: Normalmente eso se hace con un `Trigger`(`DataTrigger` o `EventTrigger`) (https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/), aunque logicamente hay varias formas de hacer las cosas. Por otro lado, pon un punto de interrupción en el `EstadoToBrushValueConverter` a ver que le está llegando

Comment: @Pikoh gracias por responder, intente hacerlo de ese modo, pero tampoco tuve éxito, cuando intentaba bindear `Estado` recibía el mismo error, y en todos los ejemplos que encontré dando vueltas por internet usaba un valor hardcodeado en xaml, no se como lo haría con un Converter

Comment: Prueba a añadir una ruta relativa en el binding. Por ejemplo, `,
Color="{Binding Path=Estado, Converter={StaticResource EstadoToBrushValueConverter},RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`.

Comment: @Pikoh No hay caso che, ahora dice que no encuentra `Estado` en `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush`

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30886629/579895). Hace uso de un converter tambien

Comment: Prueba tambien a cambiar `RelativeSource Self` por `RelativeSource Parent`

Comment: @Pikoh Llegué a la solución con el ejemplo que me pasaste, si en lugar de usar `Setter.Value` lo hago en todo en línea `<Setter Property="Background" 
                                Value="{Binding Path=Estado, Converter={StaticResource EstadoToBrushValueConverter}}"         
                        />` funciona correctamente, llegue a la conclusión por el ejemplo ese, muchas gracias!! (aunque me queda la duda de por que se da este caso)

Comment: Llegaste a probar con lo que yo te dije de `RelativeSource Parent`? Porque podría ser una cuestión de "niveles", por eso al hacerlo en una linea funciona y de la otra manera no

Comment: @Pikoh Ahora lo estaba probando pero me da error de compilación `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Parent}` es lo mismo que `TemplatedParent`? recién estoy aprendiendo de esto por eso no estoy seguro :p

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Mirate esta respuesta a una pregunta parecida que hice yo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83639/cambiar-el-color-de-una-row-en-una-gridview

Comment: Claro, porque es viernes y no estoy en mis cabales, `Parent` no existe como RelativeSource. Me refería a `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}` por ejemplo

Comment: @Pikoh lo intenté y no hubo caso tampoco, que raro :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería algo así

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TestGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Estado, Converter={StaticResource EstadoToBrushValueConverterKey}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```